# Include generated files automatically on hg archive

Tags: mercurial, generated

I have a huge Mercurial Repository with a gerated file called ".version". This file is automatically generated with a hook each time a commit is made or an update is done.

However this file is generated and NOT versioned (this always resulted in conflicts with other project developers), I want it always to be packaged when I do a

```
hg archive
```

the help page about hg archive tells that there is an option

```
hg archive -I .version
```

but is there maybe a way to perform this inclusion automatically?

I found no option relating to this in the manpage about the hgrc-file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to use hg for deployment rather than version control? perhaps you should move your hook to a deployment script instead?

Comment: what is in .version that you can't version it?

Comment: adding **.version** as project file always runs into merge conflicts when someone else than me pushed a commit to the master repository, because .version will always be updated to a version-number like **2.3.0_<hg-rev>**.

Comment: suspect you want a post-archive hook but I think we really need to know what your current hook is/what the complete contents of .version are (if its just 2.3.0_<hash> then that definitely sounds like you can do it on a post archive hook rather than update)

Comment: I also thought about this, but there is no postarchive-hook in the documentation.

Comment: all commands have a pre and post version http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks

Answer (score 1):

The archive command is not meant to be the end-all-solution to packaging your software. It just gives you a zip file or tar ball without the history, that's all.

So make a script to do this instead. The script can start by using archive to get a clean set of files:

```
$ hg archive -r 1.0 foo-repo foo-1.0
```

and then run the hook to generate the version file, copy the necessary file into the directory, build documentation, etc. Finally, just pack the directory yourself.

The morale is that getting a snapshot of the files is the smallest part of packaging software.

Comment: which hook should I run? There is no hook for postarchive, or am I wrong?

Comment: You should make a stand-alone script that you execute by hand to make your release. Nothing fancy :-) However, if you *really* want to do it as part of `hg archive`, then you can add a `post-archive` hook. All commands have `pre-` and `post-` hooks of that form.

Answer (score 0):

To run -I automatically you can set up an alias in your hgrc

```
[alias]
archive = archive -I .version
```

however I don't think -I does what you think it does. My understanding of it is it limits the contents of the archive to only things in the repo that match the pattern ".version" which as you don't have it in the repo is nothing.

If all you want in .version is version information for the revison that is being archived perhaps your current hook should be changed to a `post-archive` hook?

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. I've tried to create an alias "archive = !$HG archive -I .version $HG_ARGS" but it runs in an undefined operation I cannot specifiy further.

Comment: you shouldn't need the $HG or $HG_ARGS? or are you trying to do this as a shell alias rather than a hg alias?

Comment: well, when I run **hg archive -I .version test.tar**, I'm getting an empty tar-archive with no files within.

Comment: yes see my second paragraph. nothing in your repo matches the pattern ".version". -I is not what you want.